# pythonのselfの使い方について

Tags: python, python3

pythonのselfについて使い方をお尋ねしたいのですが

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p1 = Player("name1")
        self.p2 = Player("name2")


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.wins = 0
        self.card = None
        self.name = name
```

別のクラス内にて

```
self.p1.wins += 1
self.p2.wins += 1
```

このようにp1のwinsのように繋げて使用できるのでしょうか？
これは新しく変数を作らなくて便利だと思うのですがそのような使い方で合っているとでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

可能です。例えば、以下のようなコードで `Game with P1(user1): 1wins, P2(user2): 0wins`  というような結果を得られます。

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p1 = Player('user1')
        self.p2 = Player('user2')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Game with P1({p1_name}): {p1_wins}wins, P2({p2_name}): {p2_wins}wins".format(
            p1_name=self.p1.name,
            p2_name=self.p2.name,
            p1_wins=self.p1.wins,
            p2_wins=self.p2.wins,
        )


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.wins = 0
        self.card = None
        self.name = name


def main():
    game = Game()
    game.p1.wins += 1
    print(game)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```